# Pinescript code to find most recent bearish candle close prior to most recent high ideas

Tags: runtime-error

I am trying to find the most recent bearish candle close that occured prior to the most recent high so that i can then enter a trade if current candle closes below the most recent bearish candle, i.e. breaking structure on a pullback.

Ive got the code below and it compiles but then i get an error in the chart saying 'Error on Bar 0: 'step' in loop must be greater than zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

```
//@version=5
indicator("Bearish Close Before Highest High", overlay=true)

// Function to find the highest high index
highestHighIndex() =>
    var float hh = na
    var int hhIndex = na
    for i = bar_index - 1 to 0 by -1
        if (high[i] > hh)
            hh := high[i]
            hhIndex := i
    hhIndex

// Find the index of the most recent highest high
highestHighIndexValue = highestHighIndex()

// Find the close price of the most recent bearish candle before the highest high
var float bearishClose = na
var int bearishCloseIndex = na
for i = highestHighIndexValue - 1 to 0 by -1
    if (close[i] < open[i])
        bearishClose := close[i]
        bearishCloseIndex := i
        break

// Plotting the results
plot(bearishClose, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, title="Bearish Close Before Highest High")
```

Ive tried the coding above but it is not running on the chart, i may need to include another condition to make it work but i would've thought this code would show me the last bearish candle before we make a high, not sure what im missing.